# FieldValue arrayUnion and Cloud FireStore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have cloud fire store object like this

```
"TestCollection" : ["Test1","Test"]
```

Now I want to update this array with FieldValue.arrayUnion
because if element is same then i don't want to do anything but if it is not then I would like to add element

```
docRef.updateData({"TestCollection":FieldValue.arrayUnion(["test"])})
```

but this statement gives the error like object can not have nested array

Can anyone please help or provide same kind of example to have look for syntax ?

Comment: I have the same issue...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have found a solution.
Try this:

```
 Firestore.instance
.collection('YourCollection')
.document('YourDocument')
.updateData({'array':FieldValue.arrayUnion(['data1','data2','data3'])});
```

If it still doesn't work, try to update your Firebase.

First open a terminal fetched to your flutter project, then:

```
cd ios
pod update Firebase
```

This solution is only for mac users.

Answer (score 7):

**New FlutterFire Update 2021**

With the newest FlutterFire update there where lots of updates at the API but thankfully it hasn't changed that much for this problem. I'm talking about the newest plugins of Firebase for Flutter and specifically every plugin that is compatible with the new **firebase_core   ^0.7.0**.
So the code looks similar:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("YourCollection")
.doc("YourDocument")
.update({
      "anArray": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["data", "to", "append"])
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The other way if you have List of objects

```
Future<void> updateUserNewGroup(List<Group> data , String id) {

    List<Map> list=new List();

    if(data !=null && data.isNotEmpty){
        data.forEach((grp){
            list.add(grp.toJson());
        });
    }


    return ref.document(id).updateData({"groups": FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)}) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the existing answers, if the field does not exist you can use a set & merge. This can save you from checking if the field exists or not.

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('YourCollection')
  .document('YourDocument')
  .setData({
    'array':FieldValue.arrayUnion(['data1','data2','data3'])
  }, merge: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code I used and it worked like a charm!

```
                _firestore
                .collection('x')
                .document('xxxxxxxxxx')
                .updateData({
              'comments': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
       {'comment': "comment goes here", 'sender': "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}
              ])
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2023

Use .set() with SetOptions(merge: true)

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userService.userId).set({
    'lastLogin': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    'devices': FieldValue.arrayUnion([removeSpaces(deviceId)]),
  }, SetOptions(merge: true));
```