# How to add Field to existing document in firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new field in an existing  Document
[my firestore collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMcJt.png)

so I want to add Field like this :

```
"name" : "john",
"uid" : "ddddddddddddddddd",
"email" : "example@example.com",
"imageUrl" : "url"

"cart" : {          >>>>>> this field I want to add 
  "Productone":{
  "product name" : "productname", 
  "price" : "50"
    }
  "Productow":{
  "product name" : "productname",  
  "price" : "50"
    }
}
```

How can I do this so when the user adds a product to the cart, I can store it in firestore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `FieldValue`.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc('here is your document uid')
    .update({
  'cart': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
    {
      'Productone': {
        'product name': 'productname',
        'price': '50',
      },
    },
    {
      'Productow': {
        'product name': 'productname',
        'price': '50',
      },
    },
  ]),
});
```

It will work like `List.add`

---

One-time data reading:

```
FutureBuilder<firestore.DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: firestore.FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('your document uid')
      .get(),
  builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
    if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
      if (asyncSnapshot.data!.exists) {
        return Text(asyncSnapshot.data!.data()!['cart']);
      } else {
        return const Text('Document doesn\'t exist');
      }
    } else {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  });
```

Realtime changes reading:

```
StreamBuilder<firestore.DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: firestore.FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('your document uid')
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
    if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
      if (asyncSnapshot.data!.exists) {
        return Text(asyncSnapshot.data!.data()!['cart']);
      } else {
        return const Text('Document doesn\'t exist');
      }
    } else {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  });
```

---

Some links:

[Official `FieldValue` class documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue-class.html)

FlutterFire [FieldValue](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#field-values), [one-time read](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read), [realtime changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)

[Stack Overfolw answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52741592/14607358)

Comment: thank u It works , Now how I can get the data of the cart and show them in the screen , I want to show them with "ListView" and thank u again   ?

Comment: @bargouguisabri, I updated my anwser. But you had just search your question in the inrernet or at least create another question in Stack Overflow. UPD: Sorry, I forgot about ListView but you can do it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId)
.update({"cart":
  "Productone":
  {"product name" : "productname", 
  "price" : "50"}
  "Productow":
  {"product name" : "productname",  
  "price" : "50"}
  });
```

It's explained extremely well [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage). I believe that Firebase, specifically Flutter documentation is probably one of the best written documentations online. Props to the team.

Comment: I know but if the user adds new product to the cart I mean if he adds product 'milk' , then he adds another product 'bread', How I can  make this dynamically ?

Comment: `.update({"cart.milk":  "Milkdata"})`  if you use the `.`, you can access a key inside your map, like this for example, the `milk` key inside your `cart` map, try it, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore can accept map so 'cart' should be added as map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> cart = {
'Productone'{
"product name" : "productname", 
  "price" : "50"
}
}

 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').add({
         orders: cart,
        );
```

or

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId)
.update{ 
        orders: cart,
       );
```

Main Idea is to convert cart to Map specifically Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>