# How do I upload an array of image URLs to Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, formik

I am using Formik to handle a form submission to create new real estate properties, which includes image upload. I have everything else working: I have a function that first uploads all of the images to storage and returns the image links (the getLinks function), and then we add those URLs to the formik values object to try to upload them all to my forestore. This is the whole function.

```
const getLinks = async (values) => {
  const array = [];
  for await (const file of rawFiles) {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/houses/${file.name}`);
    uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => array.push(url));
    });
  }
return array;
};

onSubmit: async (values) => {
  getLinks(values)
    .then((imageArray) => {
      const newVals = { ...values, imageList: imageArray };
      return newVals;
    })
    .then(async (newValues) => {
      console.log(newValues);
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "properties"), newValues);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setSnackAlert({
        type: "success",
        message: "You provided values!! Congrats!",
      });
      handleOpen();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      setSnackAlert({
        type: "error",
        message: "There was an error handling your request",
      });
      handleOpen();
    });
```

The frustrating part of this, however, is that the console log directly before we submit the values to my firestore CORRECTLY logs the object with the new image URLs. Here is the console log (I purposely cut it off for sensativity, but this array does have two images)
[image]

But it does not send them up to firestore. Instead, this is what I get:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is some replication code to attempt such a problem yourself. The form is not as lengthy, but should work the same. **You will need your own firebase info to try and replicate it.**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {useFormik} from 'formik'
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
// YOU WILL NEED TO IMPORT YOUR OWN FIREBASE INFORMATION HERE FOR REFERENCE.

function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])

const selectMultipleFiles = (e) => {
    const raw = [];
    const newImages = [];
    raw.push(e.target.files);
    for (let i = 0; i < raw[0].length; i++) {
      newImages.push(URL.createObjectURL(raw[0][i]));
    }
    setImages(newImages);
  };

  const imageDisplay = images.map((image) => {
    return <img src={image} style={{height: "50px", aspectRatio: "16 / 9"}}/>
  })


const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    address: "",
    price: null,
  },
  onSubmit: async (values) => {
      getLinks(values)
        .then((imageArray) => {
          const newVals = { ...values, imageList: imageArray };
          return newVals;
        })
        .then(async (newValues) => {
          console.log(newValues);
          const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "properties"), newValues);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          alert("You provided values!! Congrats!")
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert("Sorry, there was an error.")
        });
    },
})
  
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>StackOvervlow Replication</h1>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          value={formik.values.address}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          name="price"
          value={formik.values.price}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
        <input
          accept="image/*"
          type="file"
          multiple
          onChange={selectMultipleFiles}
          />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        {imageDisplay}
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: From your screenshot it seems the pb is not limited to the images, is the document created at all?

Comment: Yes, the document is successfully created in firestore, it just does not contain the image URLs.

Comment: I'm thinking that there's a function which handles your image array that returns a promise. Could you try to change the 2nd `then()` chain to this ```
Promise.all(values).then(() => {
    console.log(newValues);
    const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "properties"), newValues);
  })
```. If it still doesn't work then you should provide a reproducible code in your question as the code above will not be able to reproduce the given behavior.

Comment: Can you share how `getLinks` is implemented, as that seems to be what populates the list of image URLs? Please click the `edit` link under your question to add this code.

Comment: I've added the getLinks function.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB That Promise did not work, I'll work on getting a code block that is reproducible.

Comment: Hi @BradyBott , have you seen my posted answer? Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications. Also see, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that `getDownloadURL()` and `uploadBytes()` is an async function that happens to return a promise (as stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)). You can use `await()` to make the code execute more synchronously. See code below:

```
const getLinks = async (values) => {
  const array = [];
  for await (const file of rawFiles) {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/houses/${file.name}`);
    const upload = await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);
    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
    array.push(imageUrl);
  }
  return array;
};
```

The above code will return an array instead of a promise.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use [`arrayUnion()`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-array-operations#firestore_data_set_array_operations-nodejs)

```js
const newVals = {...values, imageList: arrayUnion(...imageArray)}
```

[FieldValue arrayUnion and Cloud FireStore with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332758/fieldvalue-arrayunion-and-cloud-firestore-with-flutter)